# Simplify query to be made using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

Having the following schema:
[image]

Is there a way to simplify the following query and translate it to LINQ-SQL in a more friendly version?

```
  SELECT DISTINCT(c.id_credito), c.expediente, c.status
FROM creditos AS C 
JOIN acreditados AS A ON A.id_credito = C.id_credito
WHERE A.id_acreditado NOT IN 
    (SELECT  d.id_acreditado
    FROM disposiciones_acreditados AS D)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the NOT EXISTS condition which according to [this](http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx) article is faster in execution.

So the query I was looking for is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.id_credito), c.expediente, c.status
FROM creditos AS C 
JOIN acreditados AS A ON A.id_credito = C.id_credito
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT NULL AS EMPTY
    FROM disposiciones_acreditados AS D
    WHERE D.id_acreditado = A.id_acreditado)
```

With LINQ equivalent:

```
(from c in context.creditos
                           join a in context.acreditados on c.IDCredito equals a.IDCredito
                           where !(from d in context.disposiciones_acreditados
                                   select d.IDAcreditado).Contains(a.IDAcreditado)
                           select c).Distinct();
```